# UiCollectionView scrollable both horizontally and vertically

Tags: scroll, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, direction

I want to create a CollectionView that is scrollable both horizontally and vertically, but I realized that by default is scrollable only in one direction, how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a custom layout then you can specify the `collectionViewContentSize` of that layout and that is used to determine how the collection view can be scrolled.

Comment: I am creating one more layout but I don't succeded because the scroll is always one

Comment: You'll need to show the code for what you're doing.